# Other than "note that" or "NB", what is a phrase that can point out facts and that admits a shorthand in handwriting?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

I wonder if there is phrase, other than "note that" or "NB" (for some reasons), such that it functions the same as "note that" and at the same time has a short abbreviation in usage? I thought of "we have that" or "it holds that"; however, although they are in a similar role as "note that", they seem to not have a common shorthand notation.

Comment: "NB:" ... it's an abbreviation for Latin *nota bene*, "note well".

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you! Sorry I forgot to rule out that :).

Comment: Why rule it out?  Having found the perfect shorthand for "note" ("NB"), what do you need another one for?  Is there some context where you think "NB" (or just the word "Note:", which is also very short) is unsuitable?  Perhaps we need more context here.

Comment: Yes, it would help if we could understand what motivated you to ask this question.